# Why react-native-gifted-chat not displaying time correctly from firebase timestamp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-gifted-chat

I used [react-native-gifted-chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) in my app to add chat feature. Currently I am able to send and receive message from firebase properly. But, the problem is that `react-native-gifted-chat` always displays 12:00 AM of message send time. This is because it not able to convert firebase timestamp into time. Can anyone please help me how can I solve it ?

Here is the how I used **GiftedChat** component :

```js
<GiftedChat
  messages={this.props.messages}
  renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
  onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
  alwaysShowSend={true}
  textInputStyle={styles.composer}
  minComposerHeight={40}
  minInputToolbarHeight={60}
  user={{
    _id: this.props.account ?.user ?.uid,
    name: this.props.account ?.data ?.fullName,
    avatar: this.props.account ?.data ?.avatar
  }}
/>
```

Below is the code that i used for saving message in firestore :

```js
export const sendMessage = (message, groupId) => {
  return async () => {
    await firestore().collection('groupMessages').doc(groupId).collection('messages').doc(message._id).set(message).catch((e) => {
      throw {message: e.message.replace(`[${e.code}] `, '')}
    });
  }
}
```

In above code `message` is gifted chat message which contains properties : `_id`, `text`, `createdAt` and `user`.

Here is how message is stored in firebase :

[image: Firebase message structure]

When I display message :

[image: Message]

Comment: How can u save createdAt in ur code? Share it

Comment: I edited the question about how I saved createdAt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally done with temporary solution. I solve it by rendering time as custom by `renderTime` props.

```js
<GiftedChat
  ...
  renderTime={(props) => (
    <View style={props.containerStyle}>
      <CText size={10} style={{marginHorizontal: 10, marginBottom: 5}} bold color={props.position === "left" ? 'gray' : 'white'}>
        {`${props.currentMessage.createdAt.toDate().toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })}`}
      </CText>
    </View>
  )}
  ...
  ...
/>
```

I have converted `createdAt` to date and then get it in **hh:mm AM/PM** formate.

**Note:** This is just workaround solution and may not work if you are storing message and displaying message locally, because GiftedChat generated message field `createdAt` is pure javascript date object which has no `toDate()` function so you may get this type of error.

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toDate is not a function at :1:12

Answer (score 3):

From my personal experience, the easiest method to solve this is to convert `createdAt` time property into `milliseconds` before saving the data into `firebase` using `Date.parse()` method. As `react-native-gifted-chat` generate the `message` object with different time property format i.e. `"createdAt": 2020-05-08T06:56:44.698Z`. But when this property is saved into `firebase` it is shown as `timestamp` there, and when we fetch the data from `firebase` it returns the property `createdAt` with different format i.e. `"createdAt": {"_nanoseconds": 943000000, "_seconds": 1588921685}`.
This causes the issue and the app always shows current date and time `12:00 AM`. So the simple solution is to change the date format before saving it into firebase as:

```
const saveMessage = async (message) => {
    const temp = message[0];

    const createdAt = Date.parse(temp.createdAt); //<--- add this line

    const a = await db.add({ ...temp, createdAt });

    //---------your other code--------//
  }
```

Now your app will show the correct date and time when you'll fetch the data from `firebase`.

Answer (score 1):

I fix that problem with this idea also can use.

```
firestore()
      .collection('Messages')
      .where('experienceId', '==', experienceId)
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then(function (querySnapshot) {
        var messagesAll = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (documentSnapshot) {
          messagesAll.push({
            _id: documentSnapshot.data()._id,
            text: documentSnapshot.data().text,
            createdAt: new Date(documentSnapshot.data().createdAt.toDate()),
            user: documentSnapshot.data().user,
          });
        });
        setMessages(messagesAll);
      });
```